# Basic SVG background image size property

Tags: html, css, svg

I wish i never had to ask this but im confused.

So i have a basic background image on my `div` and for some reason when i set the `background-size: 246px 70px;` it does not work, only if i use !important it works.

```
.footer div.image-logo {
   height: 70px;
   width: 246px;
   background-size: 246px 70px;
   background-position: center;
   background: url(/images/svg/five_Logo.svg) no-repeat;
   margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Now basically you would think other css is overwriting it, well thats my rookie thought but it is not, when i inscpect the div with the background image, and click the tab "computed" to check the current state of the background-image-size it says `background-size:auto;`, and when i click on this to see where it gets the property `auto` it shows `246px 70px style.css?ver=1.0.5:2266 .footer div.image-logo` which is the css where i set my background size to `background-size: 246px 70px;`.

I would like to be able to set the background size without using `!important`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `background` shorthand includes `background-size:auto` and this is overriding your **previous** `background-size` statement.

Put the `background-size` statement **after** the `background` shorthand statement.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.one {
  background-size: 200px 100px;
  background: url(http://www.placebacon.net/400/300) no-repeat; /* I win */
}

.two {
  background: url(http://www.placebacon.net/400/300) no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 100px; /* I win */
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>

<div class="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is;

- background-image
- background-position
- background-size
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-origin
- background-clip
- background-color

Ex:

```
body {
  background-image: url(photo.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Therefore you might want to re-order. (Clear cookies as well)